# How to mock UserManager using GetUsersInRoleAsync in .Net Core testing?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, mocking, asp.net-identity, xunit.net

I'm trying to mock UserManager for GetUsersInRoleAsync action but not when I use mock method it always returns null value

this is code test

```
IList<ApplicationUser> users = new List<ApplicationUser>();
user = new ApplicationUser();
users.Add(user);
            
var mockUserManager = new Mock<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

var mockUserStore = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().As<IUserRoleStore<ApplicationUser>>();

UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(mockUserStore.Object,null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

var mockUserManager2 = new Mock<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(mockUserStore.Object);

mockUserManager2.Setup(x => x.GetUsersInRoleAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(users));


AuthService service = new AuthService(userManager, MockIAspNetRolesRepository, _IConfigurationRoot, MockIAccountByPeopleRepository.Object, _mapper, _logger.Object, MockIModelJoins.Object, _ISendEmailsService.Object);

ResponseApi Result = await service.GetAllUsersAdmin();

Assert.Equal(Result.ResponseObject, users);

mockUserManager2.Verify(x => x.GetUsersInRoleAsync(It.IsAny<string>()));
```

when i use the verify method, it returns

```
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x => x.GetUsersInRoleAsync(It.IsAny<string>())

Performed invocations:

Mock<UserManager<ApplicationUser>:3> (x):
No invocations performed.
```

Could you help me with this mock.

Comment: You are using separate user manager instances in the test.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you did not pass the mocked instance of `UserManager` into your `AuthService` which is being tested, so naturally its method was not called during the test.

This line in your code

```
AuthService service = new AuthService(userManager, MockIAspNetRolesRepository, _IConfigurationRoot, MockIAccountByPeopleRepository.Object, _mapper, _logger.Object, MockIModelJoins.Object, _ISendEmailsService.Object);
```

should be changed to

```
AuthService service = new AuthService(mockUserManager2.Object, MockIAspNetRolesRepository, _IConfigurationRoot, MockIAccountByPeopleRepository.Object, _mapper, _logger.Object, MockIModelJoins.Object, _ISendEmailsService.Object);
```